# replace Regex expression with the match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string: `message = 'hi <@ABC> and <@DEF>'`,
And the following Regex: `exp = '<@(.*?)>'`, so that `re.findall(exp, message)` outputs `['ABC', 'DEF']`. How can I replace the original message matches with those outputs so I get `'hi ABC and DEF'`?

Comment: Replace with `r'\1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

line = re.sub(
           r"<@(.*?)>", 
           r"\1", 
           line
       )
```